# Add custom fields to payment method

Tags: magento

I have duplicated the checkmo  doing the following below
Duplicate it as follows checkmo to checkmonew. I am using Magento version 1.9.3

Step 1 : mage/payment/block/forms + info : duplicate checkmo.php to checkmonew.php (rename inside checkmo to checkmonew)

Step 2 : mage/payment/etc/config.xml + system.xml : duplicate the checkmo parts (and rename it to checkmonew)

Step 3 : mage/payment/model/method : duplicate checkmo.php to checkmonew.php (rename inside checkmo to checkmonew)

Step 4 : design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/form + info : duplicate checkmo.php to checkmonew.php (rename inside checkmo to checkmonew)

Step 5 : design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form + info : 
duplicate checkmo.php to checkmonew.php (rename inside checkmo to checkmonew)

Now, this all seems to work but for some reason only on the backend but checkmo shows in the frontend, no problem.

I also want to add cc type option in the new payment method. I would prefer it not to be a drop down just a selection from the list of cards which are in cc type which is used in the CC payment method.

Thanks

[admin inmage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIgmt.jpg)

code

block - info

```html
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Payment
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cashmonew extends Mage_Payment_Block_Info
{

    protected $_payableTo;
    protected $_mailingAddress;

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/Cashmonew.phtml');
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getPayableTo()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_payableTo)) {
            $this->_convertAdditionalData();
        }
        return $this->_payableTo;
    }

   protected function _prepareSpecificInformation($transport = null)
    {
        if (null !== $this->_paymentSpecificInformation) {
            return $this->_paymentSpecificInformation;
        }
        $transport = parent::_prepareSpecificInformation($transport);
        $data = array();
        if ($ccType = $this->getCcTypeName()) {
            $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Type')] = $ccType;
        }
        if ($this->getInfo()->getCcLast4()) {
            $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Credit Card Number')] = sprintf('xxxx-%s', $this->getInfo()->getCcLast4());
        }
        if (!$this->getIsSecureMode()) {
            if ($ccSsIssue = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsIssue()) {
                $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Issue Number')] = $ccSsIssue;
            }
            $year = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartYear();
            $month = $this->getInfo()->getCcSsStartMonth();
            if ($year && $month) {
                $data[Mage::helper('payment')->__('Switch/Solo/Maestro Start Date')] =  $this->_formatCardDate($year, $month);
            }
        }
        return $transport->setData(array_merge($data, $transport->getData()));
    }
 
    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getMailingAddress()
    {
        if (is_null($this->_mailingAddress)) {
            $this->_convertAdditionalData();
        }
        return $this->_mailingAddress;
    }

    /**
     * Enter description here...
     *
     * @return Mage_Payment_Block_Info_Cashmonew
     */
    protected function _convertAdditionalData()
    {
        $details = false;
        try {
            $details = Mage::helper('core/unserializeArray')
                ->unserialize($this->getInfo()->getAdditionalData());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::logException($e);
        }
        if (is_array($details)) {
            $this->_payableTo = isset($details['payable_to']) ? (string) $details['payable_to'] : '';
            $this->_mailingAddress = isset($details['mailing_address']) ? (string) $details['mailing_address'] : '';
        } else {
            $this->_payableTo = '';
            $this->_mailingAddress = '';
        }
        return $this;
    }

    public function toPdf()
    {
        $this->setTemplate('payment/info/pdf/Cashmonew.phtml');
        return $this->toHtml();
    }

}
```

block - form

```html
<?php
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Payment
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license    http://opensource.org/licenses/osl-3.0.php  Open Software License (OSL 3.0)
 */


class Mage_Payment_Block_Form_Cashmonew extends Mage_Payment_Block_Form
{

    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->setTemplate('payment/form/Cashmonew.phtml');
    }

}
 /**
     * Retrieve availables credit card types
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getCcAvailableTypes()
    {
        $types = $this->_getConfig()->getCcTypes();
        if ($method = $this->getMethod()) {
            $availableTypes = $method->getConfigData('cctypes');
            if ($availableTypes) {
                $availableTypes = explode(',', $availableTypes);
                foreach ($types as $code=>$name) {
                    if (!in_array($code, $availableTypes)) {
                        unset($types[$code]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $types;
    }
```

etc - config

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Magento
 *
 * NOTICE OF LICENSE
 *
 * This source file is subject to the Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 * that is bundled with this package in the file LICENSE_AFL.txt.
 * It is also available through the world-wide-web at this URL:
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php
 * If you did not receive a copy of the license and are unable to
 * obtain it through the world-wide-web, please send an email
 * to license@magento.com so we can send you a copy immediately.
 *
 * DISCLAIMER
 *
 * Do not edit or add to this file if you wish to upgrade Magento to newer
 * versions in the future. If you wish to customize Magento for your
 * needs please refer to http://www.magento.com for more information.
 *
 * @category    Mage
 * @package     Mage_Payment
 * @copyright   Copyright (c) 2006-2017 X.commerce, Inc. and affiliates (http://www.magento.com)
 * @license     http://opensource.org/licenses/afl-3.0.php  Academic Free License (AFL 3.0)
 */
-->
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mage_Payment>
            <version>1.6.0.0</version>
        </Mage_Payment>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <models>
            <payment>
                <class>Mage_Payment_Model</class>
            </payment>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <payment_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>Mage_Payment</module>
                </setup>
            </payment_setup>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <payment>
                <class>Mage_Payment_Block</class>
            </payment>
        </blocks>
  <payment>
            <checkmonew>
                <types>
                    <AE>
                        <code>AE</code>
                        <name>American Express</name>
                        <order>0</order>
                    </AE>
                    <VI>
                        <code>VI</code>
                        <name>Visa</name>
                        <order>10</order>
                    </VI>
                    <MC>
                        <code>MC</code>
                        <name>MasterCard</name>
                        <order>20</order>
                    </MC>
                    <DI>
                        <code>DI</code>
                        <name>Discover</name>
                        <order>30</order>
                    </DI>
                    <SM>
                        <code>SM</code>
                        <name>Maestro/Switch</name>
                        <order>40</order>
                    </SM>
                    <SO>
                        <code>SO</code>
                        <name>Solo</name>
                        <order>45</order>
                    </SO>
                    <JCB>
                        <code>JCB</code>
                        <name>JCB</name>
                        <order>50</order>
                    </JCB>
                    <OT>
                        <code>OT</code>
                        <name>Other</name>
                        <order>1000</order>
                    </OT>
                </types>
            </checkmonew>
            <groups>
                <offline>Offline Payment Methods</offline>
            </groups>
        </payment>
        <payment>
            <cc>
                <types>
                    <AE>
                        <code>AE</code>
                        <name>American Express</name>
                        <order>0</order>
                    </AE>
                    <VI>
                        <code>VI</code>
                        <name>Visa</name>
                        <order>10</order>
                    </VI>
                    <MC>
                        <code>MC</code>
                        <name>MasterCard</name>
                        <order>20</order>
                    </MC>
                    <DI>
                        <code>DI</code>
                        <name>Discover</name>
                        <order>30</order>
                    </DI>
                    <SM>
                        <code>SM</code>
                        <name>Maestro/Switch</name>
                        <order>40</order>
                    </SM>
                    <SO>
                        <code>SO</code>
                        <name>Solo</name>
                        <order>45</order>
                    </SO>
                    <JCB>
                        <code>JCB</code>
                        <name>JCB</name>
                        <order>50</order>
                    </JCB>
                    <OT>
                        <code>OT</code>
                        <name>Other</name>
                        <order>1000</order>
                    </OT>
                </types>
            </cc>
            <groups>
                <offline>Offline Payment Methods</offline>
            </groups>
        </payment>
        <events>
            <sales_order_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <payment_sales_order_save_before>
                        <class>payment/observer</class>
                        <method>salesOrderBeforeSave</method>
                    </payment_sales_order_save_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_save_before>
            <sales_order_payment_save_before>
                <observers>
                    <payment_before_save>
                        <class>payment/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeOrderPaymentSave</method>
                    </payment_before_save>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_save_before>
            <sales_order_status_unassign_before>
                <observers>
                    <payment_order_status_unassign_before>
                        <class>payment/observer</class>
                        <method>beforeSalesOrderStatusUnassign</method>
                    </payment_order_status_unassign_before>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_status_unassign_before>
        </events>
    </global>
    <frontend>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Payment>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mage_Payment.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Payment>
            </modules>
        </translate>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
                <observers>
                    <payment_recurring_profile_prepare_options>
                        <class>payment/observer</class>
                        <method>prepareProductRecurringProfileOptions</method>
                    </payment_recurring_profile_prepare_options>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_type_prepare_full_options>
        </events>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <payment module="Mage_Payment">
                    <file>payment.xml</file>
                </payment>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
    <adminhtml>
        <translate>
            <modules>
                <Mage_Payment>
                    <files>
                        <default>Mage_Payment.csv</default>
                    </files>
                </Mage_Payment>
            </modules>
        </translate>
    </adminhtml>
    <default>
        <payment>
            <ccsave>
                <active>1</active>
                <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI</cctypes>
                <model>payment/method_ccsave</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Credit Card (saved)</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </ccsave>
            <checkmo>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>payment/method_checkmo</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Check / Money order</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </checkmo>
    <checkmonew>
                <active>1</active>
    <cctypes>AE,VI,MC,DI</cctypes>
                <model>payment/method_checkmonew</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Card POS</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </checkmonew>
            <free>
                <active>1</active>
                <model>payment/method_free</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>No Payment Information Required</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                <group>offline</group>
            </free>
            <purchaseorder>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>payment/method_purchaseorder</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Purchase Order</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </purchaseorder>
            <banktransfer>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>payment/method_banktransfer</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Bank Transfer Payment</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </banktransfer>
            <cashondelivery>
                <active>0</active>
                <model>payment/method_cashondelivery</model>
                <order_status>pending</order_status>
                <title>Cash On Delivery</title>
                <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
                <group>offline</group>
            </cashondelivery>
        </payment>
    </default>
</config>
```

Comment: have you create extension?

Comment: I have just done the above. Which is really duplicating checkmo and recreating this but modding ti to checkmonew as show above.

Comment: You can create extension for creating new payment.Please refer this link https://www.codealist.com/magento-1-9-create-custom-payment-method/ it will help to create custom payment method

Comment: will this give me the cctype options? as this an options i would like. and the reason i was using checkmo as a template was that it processes invoice without the capture that cc and ccsaved are doing.

Comment: can you show me the backend options?

Comment: sorry what file do you want to see?

Comment: 1 mage/payment/block/forms + info  
2 mage/payment/etc/config.xml + system.xml 
3 mage/payment/model/method 
4 design/adminhtml/default/default/template/payment/form + info : 
5 design/frontend/base/default/template/payment/form + info   : 

These are all the files i have created which one is it you want to see

Comment: I need to show admin screen shot

Comment: I have attached an image. It is call Card POS [admin inmage][1]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIgmt.jpg

Comment: is it possible to show me all file codes?

Comment: no problem what do you need to see

Comment: [link to all files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1WT4gQJ_pNjbhaps9hU1ccsL7x6rA5Xfc?usp=sharing)